# How to get first two URL path segments?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

How to get first two parts of the URL using AngularJS?

For example, I would like to get the two first path of this URL (as `admin/password/`):

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/password/57045b10eba5ca1dfd01a8fc4adb4f6c4efc6454b9454514
```

Comment: Where is the Angular app hosted? At the root of this Url or somewhere else? Are you using `html5mode` of the `$locationProvider` to get the hash out of the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Angular `$location` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location):

> **`url([url]);`**
>
> Return URL when called without any parameter.

Use it like this:

```
$scope.currentUrl = $location.url();
```

---

If you don't need the whole URL, just [**split it**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/mjjfdaju/).

Answer (score 2):

split the url on "/"

```
url = window.location.href.split("/")
```

now you have each word in a sepperate array item, then you can combine them into one string like

```
console.log(url[0] + url[1] + url[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `URL` to get the pathname, then split on `/` and take the 2 segments you want:

```
var url = "http://localhost:3000/admin/password/57045b10eba5ca1dfd01a8fc4adb4f6c4efc6454b9454514";
var pathParts = new URL(url).pathname.split('/'); //["", "admin", "password", "57045b10eba5ca1dfd01a8fc4adb4f6c4efc6454b9454514"]

pathParts.slice(1, 3).join('/') + '/'; //"admin/password/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `RegExp`.

```js
var str = 'http://localhost:3000/admin/password/57045b10eba5ca1dfd01a8fc4adb4f6c4efc6454b9454514';

var reg = str.match(/(?!:\d+)(\/\w+)(\/\w+)/g);

console.log(reg.toString().split('/').slice(1));
```